# Mongoose - when performing remove item page stuck in loading screen

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

As said When I try to remove the item from mongoDB using the mongoose the page stuck in loading.

below is my code:

**router.js**

```
router.get('/delete/:id', (req,res) => {
    try{
    todoNew.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err) => {
      //  if(err) return res.send(500,err);
      //  res.redirect('/');
    });
} catch(error)
{
    console.log(`${error}`)
}
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
      <% if(todoData) { %>
                    <% todoData.forEach(item=> { %>
                <li>
                    <%= item.test %>&nbsp;&nbsp; **<a href="/delete/<%=item._id%>**">delete</a>
                </li>
            <% }) } %>
```

**index.js**

app.use('/',homepage)

database connection and reading the data works fine but the problem is in removing the item from collection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the fact that you don't handle the response. Here is a async aproach :

```
router.get('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await todoNew.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
    res.redirect('/');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`${error}`);
    res.status(500).send('Error deleting item');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Johan. I have tried above code, but issue still exist. I just checked network tab and under the Status it shows Pending.

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: No error but under network tab it shows status code 304 (not modified)

Comment: And what the mongo shell says ?

Comment: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.. so this is the issue right ?

Comment: Yes it is. Error comes from your backend so you should refer to backend terminal when a request is made. This error  suggests that there may be a security vulnerability in your database configuration